# Passing arguments to a function: a two element tuple v. two separate arguments?

Tags: erlang

In some situations, I find it is clearer if I pass two arguments to a function, e.g. two lists, rather than passing a tuple containing the two lists.  Which is considered better style?  Any differences in efficiency?

Thanks.

Comment: Personally I prefer 2 separate arguments when acceptable (if your function is going to be used in map it is not for example) because it creates less visual noise, but it is really broad opinion based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mostly a matter of taste and a well designed API. If you follow the "don't make me think" philosophy, you might end up using both ways.

Using a tuple in an argument can sometimes be confusing, because it is non-trivial and has to be documented. For example, `lists:zip({List1, List2})` would be confusing because sending in the lists separately is more intuitive.

If the two lists belong together and will be passed through several functions before being used, it can be handy to group them together into one tuple so that functions on the way don't have to pass them separately. This makes the tuple almost a lightweight "object" that you can pass around. Functions that understand the "object" can either look into it, or split it up and call deeper functions that operate on the elements separately.

Sometimes the two lists are so related to each other that it just makes more sense to always keep them in a tuple:

```
aquire(Caller, {[Item|Free], Busy}) -> {Free, [{Caller, Item}|Busy]};
aquire(_Caller, {[], _Busy})        -> {error, no_free_items}.
```

Comment: lol. Your example is actually the problem I'm working on. I find the naming of the tuple to be problematic: UnusedBusyTuple? FreeBusy? Such names can be unwieldy, and they don't exactly make it clear what the tuple contains, where `register(frequency, spawn(frequency, init, []))` and `init() -> loop(getFrequencies(), [])` then `loop(UnusedFreqs, BusyFreqs) -> ... `seems clearer to me than `loop(FreeBusy) -> ...`--even though inside loop(), I end up passing both Lists on to other functions, e.g. allocate_freq(), deallocate_freq().

Comment: I also notice that in your example you use `_Caller` and `_Busy` rather than `_` and `_`, which I think makes the function easier to understand.  Is that recommended?

Comment: As for naming, I'd just call it `Frequencies = {Free, Busy}`. It is the same problems as how you would name an object and it fields in an object oriented language. I would argue it is recommended to keep the variable name after the underscore, because it documents the code and there's less confusion of what goes where.

Comment: So, something like this: `Free = get_frequencies(), Busy = [], Frequencies = {Free, Busy}, loop(Frequencies)` rather than `loop({get_frequencies(), []})` with loop defined in both cases as `loop(Frequencies) -> ...`?  I like the clarity in the first case--even though it is more verbose.

Comment: If the code is short and obvious, I wouldn't even create temporary variables for them during setup. It should be documented enough as it is everywhere else in the code.